# How do Elves give directions at the North Pole?

Tags: navigation, santa-claus

In this setting, Santa and all his elves live in a village centered on the North Pole. This town is basically a Christmas-themed [Hidden Elf Village](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HiddenElfVillage). Obviously, Santa leaves every year to deliver presents to the children of the world, but the elves very rarely venture outside of the magical boundary that keeps the North Pole shrouded from the rest of the world.

The question is, as seen in the title, how do these elves give each other directions to get around? Let's say a new hot chocolate bar opened in town. How would an elf describe to another elf how to get there? Normally, the cardinal directions are sufficient to get where you're trying to go, but this gets rather confusing when your town is actually centered on the North Pole. Here's a picture to help illustrate the issue:
[image: Generic Map of a Fantasy North Pole Village]
If you assume that you're standing somewhere on this red ring, you begin see that going North just leads you toward the center of town, while heading South means heading away from the center of town. To travel East or West means you are travelling along the perimeter of the circle whose radius is the distance between you and the North Pole. (I mean, I guess this is technically always true, but it isn't usually an issue in navigation.) Furthermore, if you are standing on the North Pole and you begin walking in a straight line then it doesn't matter which direction you're facing, **you are heading South**.

So how do Elves give meaningful directions to navigate their North Pole village?

Comment: I am not young, and I have never ever *ever* given anybody directions of how to go around in the city in terms of cardinal points. Nor have I ever received directions from a real live person in such terms. In fact, the only entities which have ever given me directions in terms of cardinal points are the voices of navigation software such as Google Maps, and I have always ignored them; when it says "go west" all I hear is "just drive and I will tell you what to do". Normally, people says something like "the new chocolate bar is at the corner of Street1 and Stree2, on the left as you go uptown".

Comment: Does not seem like a world building question.

Comment: The elves use transverse lat/long, which moves the poles to the equator. This is how naval vessels navigate at very high latitudes.

Comment: Is there some reason that street names wouldn't work?

Comment: Ahem, use polar coordinates.

Comment: "Go east to get to the west side".

Comment: @AlexP Before the invention of rotating map GPSs, it was statistically more common for men to give directions in terms in cardinal directions than left/right.  I believe that most people now prefer left/right only because we are less used to seeing a fixed orientation map and more used to seeing a GPS screen that turns with us, but if your elves are used to paper maps, then cardinality will be important to them

Comment: @Nosajimiki: I am pretty certain that this is an urban myth. *Maybe* in certain American cities famous for their rectangular grid of numbered streets and lettered avenues; but I can assure you that trying to navigate a typical European city using cardinal points is hopeless. It just doesn't work. For long distance trips outside the city, sure, it was and it is common; but *inside* the city? Never.

Comment: @AlexP This was the result of a study we covered in one of my college psychology classes.  Even when I lived in New Orleans where the roads all follow the path of the Mississippi River, most men used cardinal directions, even if they were only approximate.  "Go West on Claiborne" is still very intuitive even though the street runs mostly North-South in a few places. The intersection at a given spot may allow you to go North-West or South-East, but never East-West; so, West is enough information.

Comment: When interviewed, it was found that Men typically navigate by picturing the maps they've memorized in their heads; so, when they memorize a map that is always facing North, they care a lot more about if they are going up/down/left/right on thier mental map than if they are turning left or right in the physical world.  That said, GPS means we spend a lot less time studying maps, so most men don't keep those mental maps the way we used too.

Comment: @Nosajimiki: Americans are [WEIRD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology#WEIRD_bias). Has anybody ever repeated that experiment? What were the results? Do American men actually memorize maps of their own city, instead of having a mental model of what connects to what? (And at least in Romanian culture there is a massive preference to indicate "up" and "down" instead of north-east-south-west. If I say "go downstream on the Splai" everybody will understand, while if I say "go south-east on the Splai" I will get a blank look, although technically the two phrases have the same meaning.)

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond The findings were that women were more prone to navigate by landmarks and left/right, whereas men were more prone to navigate by street name and cardinal directions.  I believe it was an American study; so, there may have been a cultural bias.

Comment: @Nosajimiki Okay, maybe the system men used, but what system do WOMEN use?

Comment: @AlexP are physical maps a common possession in Romanian culture?  Because I remember when I was kid, everyone owned maps, and used them whenever they wanted to go somewhere new.  Most of the kids in my class even had a map or two on thier bedroom walls; so, they were very much things we would grow up seeing on a regular basis.  That was just how you found your way around a big city in the days prior to MapQuest and Google.

Comment: @Nosajimiki
 Sorry, I edited the question and the posts got out of order.

Comment: @Nosajimiki: Yes, I had (and drawn!) lots of maps. No, I never posted them on walls. It may be a cultural difference. We were taught and actually did use the maps to find *connections*, and then followed the connections rather than spatial directions. (Yes, we used spatial directions when navigating in the wilderness, for example on a mountain hike. Here we are speaking of navigating *in a city*.) For example, to go to Trajan Hall I used the public transportation map to find out that I needed to connect to tram number 14, and I could use any of (trolley-)buses 40, 84, or 92 for the purpose.

Comment: @AlexP Hmmm... public transit could be another cultural factor.  With buses and trams, there are very few ways between 2 points, this is very different than driving, biking, or walking through a city taking a route of your own making.  In a city grid, it is up to the driver/biker/pedestrian to plot out the course between point A and B.  It is not automatically given to you so you can look at a map, see 20 equally good ways to get there, and the most important thing is to make progress North and West until you arrive, much more like your wilderness example.

Comment: There are actually at least two functions of a coordinate system. One is to give directions (go north two blocks, then west). The second, less mentioned here. is to identify sections of the town - the North End, the West Side, the Southern Fringes'. It is the later that is really challenging to implement a system based on cardinal directions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If, at the four edges of town, there are big/prominent buildings, they could stand in for the cardinal directions. "Go towards Santa's house", "Go in the direction of the Samsung factory until you see a..." etc.

(Also, pet peeve: Santa does NOT live at the North Pole, he lives in Lapland. I'm 100% sure of this because I sent a letter to him addressed to Lapland and received a reply. Also because my Mom said so and she wouldn't lie to me.)

Comment: I really like this idea! Having large, prominent landmarks stand in for the cardinal directions makes it very clear the general area of the desired destination. It also immediately springs to mind for me distinct city districts which are characterized by their respective landmarks. It also makes it easier to distinguish where people enter and leave the city from such as "They came in the city gate in the Toymaking district" as opposed to "They came in the South gate" (Technically, every gate is a South gate).

Answer (score 9):

The North Pole is a point. A city, a village or even a hamlet are larger than a point.

As long as you are off that point, cardinal directions are still perfectly valid.

That aside, if you can't give directions with N,S,E,W, you can always use physical features of the place: "next to the barber shop, 3 houses down the road after the butcher" and so on.

Before Google maps and alike, I was never given directions with cardinal points, and I doubt many folks knew how to tell the cardinal points unless they were in some trade needing it, yet they always managed to get where they wanted to go.

Comment: "Thataway" said the elf, pointing where the inquirer needed to go...

Comment: It's a cultural thing. Where I grew up we used north/south/east/west for everything

Comment: The problem is, 'due east' is a curved line, not a straight line.

Comment: @Justin Thyme the Second - So follow the curved line. What's the problem?

Comment: @– 
chasly - supports Monica
 The problem is that to get to a point 'due east', you might be better off going north west.

Comment: This is good, practical advice! I'm not someone generally considered "good with directions" so maybe I've made this more of an issue in my head than it really is.

Answer (score 8):

## Just name the meridians

Going through the north pole to the south pole, there are lines called meridians. )You may be familiar with the prime meridian.) All the elves need to do is give names to four meridians at 90 degree angles (prime, grim, lee, and grey). Now they have useful directions (primeward, grimward, leeward, and greyward) each meaning in a direction parallel to that meridian.

Comment: Yep, and "north" and "south" would still be applicable, just headed away or towards town center. "Go 3 blocks south down Grimward Avenue, take a left at 5th street."

Comment: So, from the center, 'Go south, go east, go north' gets you where? Exactly where you started from.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond That is no different than saying "Turn left, then left, then left, then left again" on a block system.  The directions are only silly because the sequence of directions given was silly.  But one could say, Go south, then East, then South and have a very usable set of directions... especially if there is some giant marker in the center of town that you can see from anywhere.  Then North and South become the very easy to understand instructions of moving towards or away from the big landmark, and west and east mean to move clockwise or counter clockwise to it.

Comment: @Nosajimiki
 You seem to have missed the point Your 'block directions' require FOUR 90 degree turns to get to the same point. I used only three 90 degree turns. Only the turns were not 90 degrees in 3D. That's my point - at the poles, east is not 90 degrees from north.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond That only matters because you are used to it mattering.  If you grow up somewhere that North, South, East, and West have different meanings, but can still get you to anywhere you are going, then it does not really matter what they mean.  It's like the difference between Imperial and Metric, no matter what advantages one system seems to have over the other, the most useful system will always be the one you already know how to use.

Comment: I also really like this idea! Using the prime meridian and naming a few of the other ones is a clever way to move about in a familiar Cartesian way!

Answer (score 5):

**There's no problem here, just use the same methodology we do today**

The only change you need to make is that no street passing through the north pole can do so without changing names. This isn't that uncommon (you should go to Holland, where some of the older towns have street names that change every block). The circumpolar streets can be the same name around the entire latitude, but you can't have, for example, Candy Cane Lane that crosses from a latitude over the pole returning to the same latitude.

Why?

Because so long as you have that restriction, all the directions can be made with procedures you see today.

- Go north on Candy Cane Lane.
- Go south on Candy Cane Lane.
- Go north on Reindeer Ave.
- Go south on Reindeer Ave.
- Go east on Teddy Bear St.
- Go west on Teddy Bear St.

All of that makes sense, because the point of reference is always from the point where the provider of directions is standing. It would never make sense for someone standing on the north pole to say "north on...." But it makes perfect sense for someone standing on a latitude below the pole to say "north on...."

Comment: "Go east until you get beck here".

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond To be fair, that works today anywhere on the planet. :-)

Answer (score 5):

### Polar Coordinate Systems are already a thing

The kind of maps we are most familiar with are based on [Cartesian Co-ordinate systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) which annotate locations based on the combination of an origin point, and 2 perpendicular axises... but there is another equally valid way of determining where things are called [Polar Coordinate Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).  In a polar Coordinate System, instead of tracking a position using 2 distances, you track position using a distance and an angle.  So, the question is, how do you give directions in a Polar Coordinate System... as it turns out, it's actually very easy.

North is always going the be the direction towards the center of town, an South always away from it, and West will always be to move around town clockwise, and East Counter clockwise.  Assuming you can always see, or generally gauge where the center of town is, then from anywhere you are standing, gauging the direction of North, South, East, and West will always be trivial.

Can you go East until you get back to where you started? Yes, but that actually does not matter at all. Considering that a flaw in the system is like worrying about being able to get back to where you started by taking 4 left turns in a block system. Of course you can get back to where you started, the methods by which that is in option are trivial from a navigation standpoint.

Since your road system is basically a set of concentric circles, Cartesian East and West would actually not be as helpful anyway because East would eventually become North, and then West, etc... but in a Polar Coordinate system, you could go East on Polar Circle, and never have your street mysteriously change directions on you.

Comment: There is no 'east' and 'west' in a polar coordinate system. To be effective, the polar coordinate system would only work if the origin was at the point that you are, not at the actual pole. But this begs the question be asked, 'where is the zero degree line?' And, of course, a reasonable answer would be 'the ray that intersects the North Pole'. Where you want to go is the polar opposite of what you would expect.

Comment: @JustinThymetheSecond then it is a good thing someone put a big candy-cane colored rod there so that no one can ever stand on it exactly and get confused ;D.  Even in our Cardigan system, West and East are directions, not places.  We added meridians  and arbitrarily called some things Eastern or Western to make things less/more confusing... but there is no place you ever arrive at called East or West.  Theses are just relative directions.

Comment: This is a very clever solution! Using polar coordinates seems both on-theme and a serviceable solution to get around. Also the idea of an Elf pulling out a protractor because he needs to go about 400m at 67 degrees makes me chuckle internally a little.

Comment: @Redbomber fun thought, but in practical terms, the protractor is as unnecessary as the Pythagorean Theorem is to finding your way around a grid system.  I generally would not say, go 5 blocks South-West in a grid system oriented to the Cardinal Directions, I'd say go 4 blocks South, then 3 blocks West. Likewise, an elf would literally still say go 4 blocks South, then 3 blocks West... it's just that those instructions  create a different displacement in a the Polar system than on a grid, but they are just as easy to understand, communicate, and follow, and therein lies the important part.

Answer (score 4):

### use relative directions

Many people do anyway.   Tell people whether to turn right or left.

Comment: Unless you are traveling backwards. Which you are if you are facing someone to give them directions.

Comment: You give them according to the directions.  "Left onto Holly Street" may be left to neither you nor the person getting them, where you are standing, because it is relative to his facing when he reaches Holly Street.